# Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It says that Uncaught ReferenceError: message is not defined on line 73. This is line 73 and the lines that surround line 73:

```
 var username =  "";
$("#container").html("<span class = 'bot'>Chatbot: </span>" + message);
}
```

I've tried deleting the curly brace on the bottom line but then the same message appears. Does anyone know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$("#container").html("<span class = 'bot'>Chatbot: </span>" + username );`

Comment: Is the variable __message__ defined?

Comment: do you have a variable called `message`? what value are expecting to append to the string

Comment: Yes: function ai(message){
if (username.length <4)
username = message;
send_message("Nice to meet you " + username + ", how are you doing?");
}

Comment: Put your JavaScript after the jquery library import, also make sure that jquery is included in the head of the document. Ensure $ is available try use jQuery variable to get that element. And finally is the code running after the page load?! Or before, because container may not be available... Depending where are you calling the code.

Comment: This needs more details. It is also unclear where else messages is used or how it is defined. It may be a guarding issue (i.e putting a if statement to make sure messages exist or maybe it isnt defined at all?).

Answer (score -1):

The function `ai` is being called with no arguments, or an argument is supplied but the variable used in the function call is not initialized prior to the function call.

Many browsers' Developer Tools panes have Javascript debuggers. With Chrome you can set it to break automatically on uncaught exceptions, and then examine all the stack frames until you find the context where the variable should be defined but isn't.